# PyCharm uses wrong interpreter with managed Jupyter server

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

PyCharm uses the wrong python interpreter even when you select a different one using a managed Jupyter server.
[image: pycharm settings]
I noticed this first because I was getting wrong results from a dependency that was installed on the interpreter.
Debugging the code validated this. Things I tried are:

- deleting the Jupyter notebook checkpoints
- restarting the kernel
- reinstalling the dependency

But nothing worked, anyone an idea how to force PyCharm to use the right interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to resolve the issue by installing the jupyter metapackage:

```
pip install jupyter
```

(The jupyter-lab packages was already installed.)

I deleted the wrong interpreter that PyCharm was using, even though this interpreter was not selected. It obviously errored then, but revealed that PyCharm also needs the metapakcage from Jupyter. This package was installed on the interpreter that it selected automatically even when you select a different one in the UI.

So apparently PyCharm chooses a different one when it doesn't find the necessary packages, but doesn't show this in the UI. I'm not sure if this is really a bug but it should at least say somewhere in the UI the one it is actually using...